# Normal distribution mixed with discrete variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm working on this exercise and after spending the last couple of days reading about probability (not my strong suit), I'm still not sure if I'm doing it right. The exercise goes as follows:

> You're given a liquid and you have to determine whether it's liquid A
>   or B. You know that liquid A contains 14.5ml/l and liquid B contains
>   13.8ml/l of alcohol. You decide to measure the alcohol in the given liquid, however due to measurement noise the measurement will not be
>   correct. The noise will be distributed according to normal
>   distribution with standard deviation of 0.36.
>
> 1) After measuring it the first time, you get the result: 14.2ml/l.
>   What's the probability that the given liquid is A?
>
> 2) You measure it second time, this time it results into: 14.1ml/l.
>   What's the probability now? How does the probability change with N
>   measurements?

I defined a random variable $X$:
$ X \sim $ liquid is either A or B

We additionally know that $A \sim N(14.5, 0.36)$ and $B \sim N(13.8, 0.36)$.

1) I calculated the probability for both liquids as:

$P(A) = P(14.2 \le A \le 14.8) $

$P(B) = P(13.2 \le B \le 14.2) $

So to answer the first question I believe the final probability should be  $\frac{P(A)}{P(A)+P(B)}$. However I'm not sure since $P(A)+P(B)$ is larger than 1 and I might be mixing up something here. I kinda just forced the value in $[0,1]$ range. Another way that pops into my head is that I would take the original $P(A)$ probability and then multiply it with $1-P(B)$ since that event didn't occur, but that looks sketchy as well.

2) This is where I'm lost. My current attempt is (note that $m_i$ means $i$th measurement) to take conditional probabilities of all the measurements we've seen before:

$P(X=A|m_1, m_2) = \frac{P(X=A, m_2, m_1)}{P(m_2, m_1)}$ but this is mixing apples and pears. I'm not sure how to evaluate the top part since X is discrete and $m_i$ is continuous variable. What would $P(m_i)$ even mean though. Would this just be a probability to have this measurement based on A distribution and $P(X=A)$ chance to be A on both distributions A and B (like in the first question)?

If anyone could shed some light, I'd be utmost grateful!

Comment: This problem is incomplete because it does not specify (i) The a-priori probability the liquid is type A (is it 1/2?), (ii) The mean of the noise (is it 0?).   You likely should assume $P[A]=P[B]=1/2$ and the noise is mean 0.  Then $$ f_{Y|A}(y|A) = \frac{2\pi(.36)^2}e^{-\frac{(y-14.5)^2}{2(.36)^2}} \quad , \forall y \in \mathbb{R} $$  It is not correct to say $P(A)=P[14.2\leq A\leq 14.8]$ because this assumes $A$ is both an event and a random variable, and it does not consider a-priori probabilities.

Comment: You want to use Baye's rule in its "mixed" form.  Assume $Y$ is the measurement.  So the first parts want you to compute $$P[A|Y=14.2]=\frac{f_{Y|A}(14.2|A)P[A]}{f_{Y}(14.2)}$$ where $f_{Y}(14.2) = f_{Y|A}(14.2|A)P[A] + f_{Y|B}(14.2|B)P[B]$.

Comment: (i) There's no such data, only that liquid can A or B. (ii)I believe the author meant that noise is around the liquid's proper value - for A = 14.5 +- 0.36.

Comment: The first part of the problem cannot be answered unless a-priori probabilities for $A$ and $B$ are given (of course, $P[B]=1-P[A]$).  I suspect the author intended them to be $1/2$.  I observe that my latex fraction got rearranged in the first comment, I was intending that to be Gaussian $$f_{Y|A}(y|A)=\frac{1}{2\pi(.36)^2}e^{-\frac{(y-14.5)^2}{2(.36)^2}}$$

Comment: I'm wondering how you derived the equation for $f_{y|A}$? It looks a bit off to be honest, should $e$ be in the denominator?

Comment: Aha I see, I'll assume apriori probabilities to be $1/2$ as suggested. So $f_{y|A}$ is basically just the value if we only had liquid A. I'm just a bit sceptic about using it as a "probability", isn't this defined as PDF, but we need CDF for probabilities? Sorry if it's a dumb question.

Comment: Yes, $f_{Y|A}(y|A)$ is the conditional PDF for the measured value $Y$, given the liquid is type $A$.  You want to compute $P[A|Y=14.2]$.  The problem is that the event $\{Y=14.2\}$ has probability zero!  But, you can imagine a small value $\delta>0$ so that $P[Y \in [y, y+\delta]]>0$ and then by the usual formula: $$ P[A|Y\in [y, y+\delta]]= \frac{P[Y\in[y,y+\delta]|A]P[A]}{P[Y\in[y,y+\delta]]} \approx \frac{(f_{Y|A}(y|A)\delta)P[A]}{f_Y(y)\delta}$$ and canceling $\delta$ motivates the mixed formula.

Comment: Woah that's pretty awesome! The first part is clear as a day, thank you very much!

Comment: With this knowledge, I attacked the second part like this ($Y_i$ is the $i$-th measurement):

$$P(A|Y_1,Y_2) = \frac{P(Y_1|A, Y_2)\cdot P(A|Y_2)}{P(Y_1|Y_2)}$$

since measurements are independent, we can write this as:

$$\frac{P(Y_1|A)\cdot P(A|Y_2)}{P(Y_1)\cdot P(Y_2)} = \frac{f_{Y|A}(Y_1|A) \cdot P(A|Y_2)}{f_Y(Y_1)\cdot f_Y(Y_2)}$$

where we use the same formulas as for the first part.

@Michael Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: And for 3 it would be:

$$P(A|Y_1, Y_2, Y_3) = \frac{P(A, Y_1, Y_2, Y_3)}{P(Y_1, Y_2, Y_3)} = \frac{P(Y_3|A) \cdot P(A|Y_1, Y_2) \cdot P(Y_1, Y_2)}{P(Y_1, Y_2, Y_3)} = \frac{P(Y_3|A) \cdot P(A|Y_1, Y_2)}{P(Y_3)}$$

from which we can derive general formula:

$$P(A|Y_1, Y_2 ... Y_{N-1}, Y_N) = \frac{P(Y_N|A)}{P(Y_N)} \cdot P(A|Y_1 ... Y_{N-1})$$

where we already know the probability for $P(A|Y_1 ... Y_{N-1})$ from the previous measurement.

Comment: Or you can say that $$P[A|(Y_1, ..., Y_k)=(y_1,...,y_k)] = \frac{f_{Y_1,...,Y_k|A}(y_1,...,y_k|A)P[A]}{f_{Y_1,...,Y_k}(y_1,...,y_k)}$$